# Fedora 23: "dnf update" stuck at "Running transaction"

Tags: fedora, dnf

For a few days now I'm having issues running `dnf update` under my Fedora 23 installation.

After updating the package info and downloading the packages `dnf` seems to be stuck at "Running transaction". This is what the terminal shows:

```
[...]
[SKIPPED] xorg-x11-server-common-1.18.3-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                                           
[SKIPPED] xorg-x11-server-Xwayland-1.18.3-1.fc23.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                                         
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
```

I don't see anything suspicious in journalctl. I already tried cleaning `dnf` with:

```
rm /var/lib/rpm/__db.*
cd /var/cache/dnf
rm -rf *
dnf clean all
```

The same happens when I try to install a new package via `dnf install`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For how long does it stay stuck? Minutes, hours...?

Comment: I waited for ~15mins before aborting

Comment: What is your hardware configuration? I'm thinking there's a chance there's some I/O bottleneck here.

Comment: I'm running inside a virtualbox with a memory size of 8 gb and a dedicated harddrive for the VM (SSD, connected via USB 3.0). I never experienced any problems with dnf update before. The problems only started a few days back.

Comment: I say leave it a bit more, especially since it's a VM on an external disk, and also loog in the logs for anything eye-catching.

Comment: Highly similar problem here.

Comment: @schaiba, chances are if you check with top and you do not see anything happening that the tool is somehow stuck. It's probably only a verification step so certain not going to be a problem with the installation itself, but rather bad for the rep in regard to the reliability of the tool...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After waiting for several hours `dnf` still was stuck on Running transaction. However after pressing `Ctrl+C` numerous times it continued. After it was done installing and verifying it was stuck again. `Ctrl+C` to the rescue it exited normally and all the updated packaged were installed... I still don't know what happened and also don't see any error in the logs. Hopefully it will work as expected the next time.

Comment: I installed Fedora version 25 then switched to Rowhide and ran in this problem. Only the Ctrl-C does not seem to work at all. (i.e. it looks like they prevent you from using Ctrl-C)

Comment: This worked for me too. I even used Ctrl + \ and it still worked.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem so I just changed the priority of the dnf process to -10 from another shell, and the issue was solved.

```
renice -n -10 -p <pid>
```

Probably, dnf tries to do so many processing and since it runs with default priority, it takes so much time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got that problem after I upgraded the whole platform (Fedora 25) to *Rawhide* (future Fedora 26). After the upgrade was done, I tried to install `cmake`, but a reboot was needed to finish up all the RPM database synchronization. After a reboot, everything worked like a charm as expected.